# How can i register my app in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I want to connect my Microsoft Azure bot to CRM Bitrix24. I am stuck on the point, where do i need to change the password of the App. To do this in "Settings" of this App i need to click "Manage" but when i am clicking it - i get "Not found" error.

I have tried to create new bots, wait for ~10 hours because support told me that Azure security system can be up to 8 hours. Have tried to register bot with a help of `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application/{app id}` link. Nothing is working for now.

Comment: probably best bet is to ask support to help you with changing the password

Comment: @4c74356b41 i have chatted with them for last 3 days, they have asked me to make a question there and their engineer specialists will answer me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a password, however you *can* create and delete passwords.

To do so, first navigate in Azure to 'App registrations'. You can click on the 'All Services' button and search/access the page from there.

[image]

[image]

Click into 'App registrations', select your bot, and then select 'Certificates & secrets' in the menu.

[image]

From here you can click under the 'New client secret' button located under 'Client secrets'. Be sure to record the newly generated password as it will only be visible once.

Side note: The 'Manage' button in the bot settings appears to be working. Not sure if it was fixed since you posted your issue. If you are still unable to access, try logging out and clearing your browser history/cache.

Hope of help!